# Delete record MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to delete a record from 
Db and I get methodnotallowed:
 HomeController

```
public function index()
    {
        $YourData = DB::table('packages')
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'packages.user_id')
            ->select('users.name as username','packages.*',DB::raw('SUM(packages.entry_nr) as entries'))
            ->where('users.id', Auth::id())
            ->get();


             $id =Auth::user()->id;
            $lesson = DB::select("
            SELECT *
            FROM lessons t
            inner join bookings b
            on b.lessons_id =t.id
            where b.user_id = ".$id."
            and t.date > now() 
            ");
            return view('home') ->with('YourData', $YourData)
                                ->with('lesson', $lesson);

    }
public function destroy($lessonId,$authId)
{    $book= Booking::where('lessons_id',$lessonId)
        ->where('user_id',$authId)
        ->delete();

    return redirect()->action('HomeController@index');
}
```

and my form is like this

```
<form method="post" class="table_content_form">
        <form  method="post" action="{{action('HomeController@destroy', $ls->id, Auth::user()->id)}}">
          {{ csrf_field() }}
                <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-danger" type="submit" >Rimuovi</button>
        </form>
```

My Route `Route::delete('/delete/','HomeController@destroy');`

Thanks in advance!I am trying to learn step by step!

Comment: what is your route code

Comment: @afsalc  `code Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');`

Comment: @Option these are the only two routes that I have `code Route::delete('/delete/','HomeController@destroy'); `

Comment: I noticed you already included it so deleted my comment and provided an answer for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
Route::post('/delete/{id}/{userId}','HomeController@destroy')->name('deletedata');

public function destroy($lessonId,$authId)
{    $book= Booking::where('lessons_id',$lessonId)
        ->where('user_id',$authId)
        ->delete();

    return redirect()->action('HomeController@index');
}

<form method="post" class="table_content_form">
        <form  method="post" action="{{route('deletedata', [$ls->id, Auth::user()->id])}}">
          {{ csrf_field() }}
                <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-danger" type="submit" >Rimuovi</button>
        </form>
```

---

**Updated Answer ::**

**In your route file changes.**

```
Route::post('/delete/{id}','HomeController@destroy')->name('deletedata');
```

**In your controller file Changes.**

```
public function destroy($lessonId)
{    
$user_id = Auth::user()->id;
$book= Booking::where('lessons_id',$lessonId)
        ->where('user_id',$user_id)
        ->delete();

    return redirect()->action('HomeController@index');
}
```

**In your Form Changes**.

```
        <form  method="post" action="{{route('deletedata', $ls->id)}}">
          {{ csrf_field() }}
                <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-danger" type="submit" >Rimuovi</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: "Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::destroy(), 0 passed and exactly 2 expected"

Comment: @Jonathan: Let me check

Comment: Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

Comment: @Jonathan: Your record was deleted or not?

Comment: no it wasnt I refresh the page still there even in the table

Comment: can you please echo $lessonId and $authId in your controller's destroy method.

Comment: I just did and it redirects http://localhost:8000/delete/5 page not found no data echoed

Comment: Yes pbl is that your route is like '/delete/{id}/{userId}' and your form action is made by like this ' localhost:8000/delete/postid' , So userid is not append on your form ur so , error is arrived.

Comment: @Jonathan Please Check My Updated Answer.

Comment: I just tried your code and MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Comment: @Jonathan Can you Please Change your form code to my form.Because you are declared the form 2 times.

Comment: When I try sb's code I chage all,with routes and controller and view

Comment: it throws this MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Comment: @Jonathan Yes, Why ? because you writing the form 2 times in your code. Can you please replace my form code with your current code, and also follow my updated answer.

Comment: just did still the same IDK driving me insane

Comment: join in my chat and see my full code this is madness

Answer (score 0):

try to use `route()` and `method_field('DELETE')` and receive `$request` variable in controller
your form should be like this

```
<form action="{{ route('Booking.destroy',$ls->id) }}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete
    </button>
</form>
```

your route should be like this

```
Route::post('/delete/{$id}','HomeController@destroy')->name('Booking.destroy');
```

your controller should be

```
public function destroy(Request $request,$lessonId){
    $id =Auth::user()->id;
    $book= Booking::where('lessons_id',$lessonId)
    ->where('user_id',$id)
    ->delete();
    //Or you should try 
    //$book=Booking::destroy($lessonId);
    $request->session()->flash('message','Product deleted successfully');
    return redirect()->action('HomeController@index');
}
```

Comment: let me know url page not found

Comment: localhost:8000/delete/5

Comment: reset your route and cache

Comment: run these command php artisan route:clear,php artisan cache:clear,and restart the server